# Why is the flair picture for stackoverflow not scaled/resized?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair

If a picture is worth a thousand words, then:

[image: Flair from Sept 06]

At first I thought that Stack Overflow wasn't resizing my normal flair picture from myOpenID, but then I remembered that I linked in my Facebook account recently.

My guess is that the flair code is not resizing my Facebook profile picture to fit in the available space, and instead cropped it.

Comment: [Well, actually](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-17.html), [a picture is worth 140 characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891643/twitter-image-encoding-challenge)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trigger here is that your facebook profile picture is just ever so slightly wider than it is tall.  This case is rare, and wasn't handled correctly.

A fix will go out with the next build.

Due to the way flair is cached, it may take up to 24 hours after that build for you to see it take effect.

Comment: Cool.  Glad to have added a strange case to your day's events.