# Why is the Facebook imported profile picture cropped on the right?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

As a follow up on the recently fixed [flair bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105265/166234), but possibly related, I notice that my profile picture that Stack Overflow is importing from Facebook appears cropped on the right side.

To wit:

[image: my profile picture from facebook]   [image: my profile picture from Stack Overflow]

The picture is subsequently right cropped in the flairs as well.  I don't think, but can't certainly state, that the image was cropped prior to the aforementioned fix.

Comment: Maybe the algorithm thinks you're a conservative in US politics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook doesn't expose a way to get a square version of profile pictures large enough for our purposes.

So we take the largest profile image available and cram it into a square.  In the typical (portrait orientation) case we center the image, but we cannot do the same for landscape pictures without some really nasty hacks.  Honestly, the portrait fix is already pretty nasty; the assumption of square avatars is very very deep in our system.

I consider this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) for now, as the only true fix is to start hosting Facebook profile images on our infrastructure; which has all sorts of legal, scaling, and sync'ing issues.